# GRASS GIS r.walk issue

Tags: raster, grass-gis, cost-path

I have been playing around with GRASS GIS to do a simple cost analysis of getting from point A to point B. I have a DEM clipped to the study area, a raster containing the friction costs, as well as the start and end points. All the data has the same projection, and it matches the project location.

However, whenever I attempt to run the process, there is an error with the output raster. If a simple name like 'output' is used, an error is raised that states 'Raster output map  not found', or if 'output@Dawson' is used it raises an error that it is an illegal file name. If one of the raster maps for the drop down box is used, an error is raised that the output already exists.

Does r.walk require an empty raster to write the results, or am doing something wrong?

Comment: Try an output name that is **not** a reserved work. Something like 'my_output'. To overwrite an exisiting raster you need to tick the "Allow overwrite..." checkbox in the "Optional" pane.

Comment: Checking the 'Allow output files to overwrite existing files' allowed r.walk to work, unfortunately the output is a 1x1 raster. I'll keep tinkering with the settings and hopefully something works.

Comment: Rule number one with GRASS: always **setup the region** before doing anything else. This must include both the extent and pixel size.

Comment: Setting the pixel size pretty much solved all the problems. Thanks.